# How to sort a list of objects in a GridView in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a list of objects

```
List<News> theNews = controlClass.ListNews();
```

ListNews() is loaded with News objects from a dataset.

then I have a gridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvNews" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvNews_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gvNews_Sorted">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="titNew" HeaderText="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dateNew" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="dateNew" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="typeNew" HeaderText="Type" />
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="See More" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I store said list into this GridView and then I have the following code to Sort it

```
    private void LoadNews()
    {
        this.gvNews.DataSource = controlClass.ListNews();
        this.gvNews.DataBind();
        ViewState["dt"] = controlClass.ListNews();
        ViewState["sort"] = "Asc";
    }

    protected void gvNews_Sorted(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable result = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        if (result.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            if(ViewState["sort"].ToString()=="Asc")
            {
                result.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
                ViewState["sort"] = "Desc";
            }
            else
            {
                result.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Asc";
                ViewState["sort"] = "Asc";
            }
            gvNews.DataSource = result;
            gvNews.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

*Yet this leads me to the following error:
    Type 'MySolution.News' in Assembly 'MySolution, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
I can't seem to store my list in a ViewState, is there a way around this?*

**UPDATE:**
I've made my News Class Serializable but I get the following error when I click the Date header in the gridview

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MySolution.News]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.**

**UPDATE NUMBER 2**: I modified my gvNews_Sorted Method to match with @Dr.Stitch 's Answer.

```
protected void gvNews_Sorted(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   List<News>result = (List<News>)ViewState["dt"];
   if (result.Count>0)
   {
      if(ViewState["sort"].ToString()=="Asc")
      {
        result = result.OrderBy(e.SortExpression + " Desc").ToList();
        ViewState["sort"] = "Desc";
      }
      else
      {
         result = result.OrderBy(e.SortExpression + " Asc").ToList();
         ViewState["sort"] = "Asc";
      }

      gvNews.DataSource = result;
      gvNews.DataBind();
   }
}
```

and I'm getting the following error in the line

```
result = result.OrderBy(e.SortExpression + " Desc").ToList();
```

[image]

**UPDATE 3:** I made further changes trying Dr Stitch's new answer, now despite no longer crashing it fails to do nothing at all, when I click the header nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saving a `List<News>` object

```
ViewState["dt"] = controlClass.ListNews();
```

But trying to retrieve a `DataTable` object

```
DataTable result = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
```

You have to change your `gvNews_Sorted` to this:

```
protected void gvNews_Sorted(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   List<News>result = (List<News>)ViewState["dt"];
   if (result.Count>0)
   {
      if(ViewState["sort"].ToString()=="Asc")
      {
        if ("titNew" == e.SortExpression)
            result = result.OrderByDescending(r => r.titNew).ToList();
        //...do it to all the fields

        ViewState["sort"] = "Desc";
      }
      else
      {
        if ("titNew" == e.SortExpression)
            result = result.OrderBy(r => r.titNew).ToList();
        //...do it to all the fields
         ViewState["sort"] = "Asc";
      }

      gvNews.DataSource = result;
      gvNews.DataBind();
      ViewState["dt"] = result;
   }
}
```

Make sure the `LoadNews()` only calls on non-postback event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
     LoadNews();
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error in ´result = result.OrderBy(e.SortExpression + " Desc").ToList();´ https://i.gyazo.com/631d1f98de0f4239be379ff72681b7b5.png

Comment: put the actual error and not image. i have no access to that sorry.

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: try to remove `.ToList()`

Comment: removed `.ToList()` and nothing

Comment: update the answer please try. it seems you need to detect the e.SortExpression as well and use linq properly.

Comment: what If I only want to sort using the date column, do I just change ´result = result.OrderByDescending(r => r.dateNew).ToList();´ ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115684/discussion-between-lucas-araujo-and-dr-stitch).

Comment: no access to chat. if the post solve you question please marked it as answer. if you have another question please post a new one. :)

Comment: your answer did not fully solve my problem yet since it no longer crashes but it fails to change the order of the list

Comment: check the values of your date fields maybe its almost the same?

Comment: they're datetime fields and I can confirm this does not change the order, does anything change if I add that my select query from my control class has oderby IdNew??

Comment: where do you call LoadNews()? make sure you're filtering IsPostBack. update the answer.

Comment: I have it on Page_load and yes I filter IsPostBack

Comment: what is your filter? it supposed to be `!IsPostBack` and not `IsPostBack`

Comment: is there anyplace else that you call `controlClass.ListNews()` ?

Comment: lmao my bad I had the sort expression from the if that check if sort expression is a table to the field name isntead of the sort expression that I defined on the gridview code a million thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that you are performing some operation on the `News` class that requires that it be `serialized`, but it doesn't have an attribute marking it as `serializable`.

Make sure all the fields are `serializable` types, and then attach the `Serializable` attribute to your class:

```
[Serializable]     
public class News
{

}
```

Comment: how do I make my fields and encapsulated variants serializable?

Comment: I updated my question with new information regarding your answer

Comment: You are storing List in ViewState but you are casting to DataTable while retrieving. So cast to list than DataTable. Or convert list to DataTable while getting from ViewState